# Cómo copiar un arreglo de Strings a otro arreglo de tipo Int?

Tags: java, array, string

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para ordenar números con el `Bubble Sort`. La cosa es que al momento de copiarlo y mostrarlo me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está mi código:

```
public class OrdenamientoBurbuja extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int auxiliar;
String delimitador = ", ";
String datos;
int cantidadNumeros;
int lista[] = new int[cantidadNumeros];
String entrada[];
```

//

```
 private void btnOrdenarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    datos = txtEntrada.getText();
    entrada = datos.split(delimitador);



    //método burbuja
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < lista.length; j++) {
            auxiliar = lista[i];
            lista[i] = lista[j];
            lista[j] = auxiliar;
        }
    }

    //mostrar en Lista ordenada:
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        txtSalida.setText(String.valueOf(lista[i]) + ", ");
    }
}                                          

private void    btnGuardarListaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    //agrego los datos al arreglo
    for(int i=0; i< entrada.length; i++){
        entrada[i] = String.valueOf(lista[i]);
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber cuál es la mejor manera de copiar el arreglo `entrada` al arreglo `lista`

Answer (score 3):

> Quisiera saber cuál es la mejor manera de copiar el arreglo entrada al arreglo lista

Puedes hacerlo utilizando [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

```
for(int i=0; i< entrada.length; i++){
   lista[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada[i]);
}
```

Nota: Es importante que los tamaños de los arrays sean identicos, de lo contrario puedes tener problemas en el copiado de datos al intentar acceder a una posición fuera de los límites del array

Para ello puedes:

- instanciar a tu array como `int [] lista = new int [entrada.lenght];` de manera que ambos tengan igual tamaño
- asegurarte que la lógica que asigna un valor a la variable `cantidadNumeros;` sea coherente con el tamaño del array `entrada`

Comment: +1 También hay que estar seguros de que los strings contienen numeros (enteros) en formato decimal... y sin espacios. Si no estamos seguros de lo últimos, puede convenir `Integer.parseInt(entrada[i].trim());`

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, he tomado en cuenta sus sugerencias y tambien he instanciado desde un principio el arreglo entrada de esta forma `String entrada[] = new String[lista.length]` . Pero ahora me sale un error diferente: **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException**

Comment: y justo en esta línea:

      `for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
                lista[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada[i].trim());
            }`

Comment: Brian, eso te pasa porque cuando inicializas `lista` el tamaño es `0` ya que no has dado valor a `cantidadNumeros` y accedes a los arreglos `lista[i]` y `entrada[i]` en el mismo bucle, para evitarlo, inicializa `lista` en el metodo `btnOrdenarActionPerformed` despues de crear `entrada` de esta manera: `lista = new int[entrada.length];`

Answer (score 1):

Para copiar el arreglo entrada (Strings) al arreglo lista (Integers), basandose en tu código, se realizaría de esta forma :

```
String delimitador = ", ";
String datos;
String entrada[];

//obtienes un arreglo de strings con split().
  entrada = datos.split(delimitador);
//dimensionas el array lista
int lista[] = new int[ entrada.length ];

//creas un loop donde obtienes los valores del array de strings, y los conviertes a int por medio de Integer.parse():

for(int i=0; i< entrada.length; i++){
   lista[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes usar [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) te recomiendo el uso de streams

```
int[] lista = Stream.of(entrada).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Esto va a hacer un stream del `String[]`, lo mapeara a una `IntStream` usando el metodo `Integer::parseInt` y lo volvera a transformar en array.

Comment: Muy interesante. Quisiera informarme acerca de esta clase Stream

Comment: @Brian http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta aca:

```
int cantidadNumeros;
int lista[] = new int[cantidadNumeros];
```

La variable **cantidadNumeros** no le asignas ningun valor, por ende, el tamaño de la lista tampoco esta definido y cuando haces el recorrido te tira la excepcion porque accede a un lugar que no hay nada.

Answer (score -2):

```
String [ ] entrada = (String)lista.clone();
```

Comment: responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, editalo y explica esto

Comment: Aunque esta publicación puede ser de ayuda para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Por favor, edítala para añadir más información: ¿qué es lo que hace el código? ¿cómo o dónde iría dentro del código de la pregunta? ¿Cómo funciona o por qué solucionaría el problema? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).